# Jquery on focus event with an html select tag

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to change the background of a dropdown. For some reason it now requires two clicks to select an item, instead of one click.

What i cannot find out is why this occurs and an efficient workaround or better yet a fix. 
This seems to be occuring in ie7 & ie 8 (had a friend test it on their box) Below is the exact code we are using to test this issue.

-----------------------------COMPLETE MARKUP --------------------------------

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .yellowBackground, .yellowBackground > * > *
    {
        background-color: #FFFF79;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').focus(function() {

            $(this).addClass('yellowBackground');

        })
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <select>
        <option value="A">Option 1</option>
        <option value="B">Option 2</option>
    </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you found this is not unique to you upon searching the web, then you should provide some links to back this claim up.

Comment: I am not doubting you, just hoping that more detail would be provided elsewhere.

Comment: Yup, completely understand let me pull them up and post in next comment

Comment: This only occurs in IE 7, I should've clarified sorry.

Comment: @josh stodal
Sorry I was mistaken, the website talked about the 'OnFocus' event not the jquery 'focus' event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a [known issue in IE7 and forward](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/04e20cfd-44a2-4f06-a87f-c39a69a172bb).

As mentioned, one alternative is to use the onmousedown event to bypass this.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').mousedown(function() {

            $(this).addClass('yellowBackground');

        })
    });
```

This won't work with tabbing over to the dropdown, though onfocusin is supposed to work as well (but it doesn't exist in jquery).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is more likely to do with how the `<asp:DropDownList>` control has been used. Without seeing the server-side code, it's difficult to get a look at the fuller picture. Can you also provide the aspx markup and code-behind for your page?

Comment: just added a code for a simple page to illustrate. This only occurs in IE 7. sorry i didnt clarify that earlier

Comment: do you `AutoPostBack=true` on the `<DropDownList>` ?

Comment: Using the sample code above adding autopostback doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately I don;t have IE7 here at the moment, but will be able to look tomorrow. Not seeing it in FireFox or IE6 though.

Comment: i appreciate your time looking into this.